# Windows7 tethering and WIFI

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, iphone, tethering

If my Windows7 machine has a WIFI connection *and* is tethered through my iPhone, will it use both connections to the internet?

Comment: If you are tethered to the iPhone then you are using the WiFi connection unless you have two seperate 802.11 devices on your machine.

Answer (score 2):

No. In general, networking works by sending packets to the "fastest" (Shortest *metric* value) path available to the destination. This is called *routing*. You can dump a table of the active routes on your system with

```
route print
```

on the command line.

When you have an iPhone tether and Wifi both active on your system, by default the Wifi is assigned a lower metric ("faster"), so if both are available, the system will always send packets to the wireless interface. This is by far the simplest way to do things, and takes care of the issue that even if you have multiple working routes to the Internet, an individual connection must only use one of them. If your system receives a packet over the Wifi, it must send the reply over the Wifi because the iPhone will have a different IP address and the other computer won't recognize the reply if it comes from the iPhone.

---

There are special routers which support what is known as **Multi-Homing**, where the router tries to actively divide connections between multiple routes. It must still ensure that individual connections use the same route to get to the internet, but it's able to divide up say, all of your connections to `google.com` over your iPhone, and all of your connections to `superuser.com` over your WiFi.

This would allow you to "use" both connections at once.

Comment: "by default the Wifi is assigned a lower metric"...what if the tethered connection is faster, is it sophisticated enough to recognize that? (it seems to be, based on my system's behavior).

Comment: No. It's been a while since I actually looked at my routes while tethering, and so I may be wrong that the default metric places WiFi faster than tethering, but it makes no effort to find out how fast the connection really is. It simply looks at the connection type (Wired Ethernet, Wireless Ethernet, Bluetooth Ethernet, USB Tether, Modem) and gives it a default metric based on that.